# How toget a list of "fastest miles" from a set of GPS Points

Tags: python, algorithm, geolocation

I'm trying to solve a weird problem. Maybe you guys know of some algorithm that takes care of this.

I have data for a cargo freight truck and want to extract some data. Suppose I've got a list of sorted points that I get from the GPS. That's the route for that truck:

```
[
    {
        "lng": "-111.5373066",
        "lat": "40.7231711",
        "time": "1970-01-01T00:00:04Z",
        "elev": "1942.1789265256325"
    },
    {
        "lng": "-111.5372056",
        "lat": "40.7228762",
        "time": "1970-01-01T00:00:07Z",
        "elev": "1942.109892409177"
    }
]
```

Now, what I want to get is a list of the "fastest miles". I'll do an example:

Given the points:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F
```

the distance from point A to point B is 1 mile, and the cargo took 10:32 minutes. From point B to point D i've got other mile, and the cargo took 10 minutes, etc. So, i need a list sorted by time. Similar to:

```
B -> D: 10
A -> B: 10:32
D -> F: 11:02
```

Do you know any efficient algorithm that let me calculate that?

Thank you all.

PS: I'm using Python.

**EDIT:**

I've got the distance. I know how to calculate it and there are plenty of posts to do that. What I need is an algorithm to tokenize by mile and get speed from that. Having a distance function is not helpful enough:

```
results = {}
for point in points:
  aux_points = points.takeWhile(point>n) #This doesn't exist, just trying to be simple
  for aux_point in aux_points:
    d = distance(point, aux_point)
    if d == 1_MILE:
      time_elapsed = time(point, aux_point)
      results[time_elapsed] = (point, aux_point)
```

I'm still doing some pretty inefficient calculations.

Comment: What exactly do you want help with ?  Sorting a list of mile times fastest first ?  (Probably not !)  Calculating distances in miles between lat/long pairs ?

Comment: Velocity = Distance / Time , surely thats all you need?  Calculating distance between two lat/longs is very easy and can be found on many websites, calculating time difference is easy too.  The sorting really depends how many items your going to be sorting.

Comment: Assuming straight lines, I'd go with Pythagoras' Theorem and speed=dist/time. Use `time.strptime` and `calendar.timegm` to get time into a standard format for you to play with

Comment: I've got the distance. I can do it manually or using geopy. That's not the problem. Maybe I didn't write my question well. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Done. See my problem? I have a way to get the distance and the time elapsed between 2 points. But I don't have a good way to calculate that for all points.

Answer (score 1):

If you have locations and timestamps for when the location data was fetched, you can simply do something like this:

```
def CalculateSpeeds(list_of_points_in_time_order):
  """Calculate a list of (average) speeds for a list of geographic points."""

  points = list_of_points_in_time_order
  segment_start = points[0]
  speed_list = []

  for segment_end in points[1:]:
    dt = ElapsedTime(segment_start, segment_end)
    # If you're looking at skipping points, with a slight risk of degraded data
    # you could do something like "if dt < MIN_ELAPSED_TIME:" and indent
    # the rest of the loop. However, you'd need to then check if the last point 
    # has been accounted for, as it might've been too close to the last considered
    # point.
    d = Distance(segment_start, segment_end)
    speed_list.append(d/dt)
    segment_start = segment_end
  return speed_list
```

You've said (in comments) that you can do this for a single pair, so all you need to do is to do it for all consecutive pairs.

Comment: Yes, I already have this. I'm looking for a better algorithm. For any GPS route, I've got no less than 1000 points. Doing this kind of calculation is almost impossible. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't think there's any "magic short-cut" to getting the answer you want. It does depend on what you're actually trying to accomplish, but I read the question as "I want to find all inter-point speeds" and you can't get that without, well, calculating them. It might be possible to drop the number of segments you compute a speed for, by (say) skipping intermediate points until you have a minimum elapsed time (since elapsed time is probably cheaper to compute than distance).

Comment: Yes, maybe. But that wouldn't be really robust. I've been taking a look at classification mechanisms, like K-nearest neighbor algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm). I hope there's a better way.

Comment: Have you actually tried the calculation as shown above? Doing this for a thousand points shouldn't take more than one second, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have `n` such points, there will be `n - 1` "legs" on the journey. You can form that list by simply:

```
legs = []
for i in xrange(n - 1):
  legs.append(build_leg(point[i], point[i + 1]))
```

Assuming `point` is the list of points and `build_leg()` is a function that accepts two points and computes the distance and average speed.

The above loop will call `build_leg` with first point 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, and so on up until `n - 2` and `n - 1` which are the two last points.

Answer (score 0):

I've grown to love the sliding window, and it may be helpful here.  Same concept as the other answers, just a slightly different method.

```
from itertools import islice
def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result


results = {}
# presort your points in time if necessary
for point_a, point_b in window(points):
    d = distance(point_a, point_b)
    if d == 1_MILE:
        time_elapsed = time(point_a, point_b)
        results[time_elapsed] = (point_a, point_b)
```